# How can I calibrate two monitors individually in Windows7?

Tags: software, color-management, windows, windows-7

I have 2 monitors, a Dell U2410 and a Wacom Cintiq 12 UX. I have an eye1Match calibrator & software. I was told by the people @ Xrite, that even if I calibrate both devices, Windows will only apply one of them. I am running Window 7 Professional 64 bit. I really don't care if the Dell display is off because I only use it for pallettes. I need to have the Cintiq as accurate at possible. My problem lies in Bridge. If I look at a RAW file in Bridge on the Dell, it looks pretty good. If I bring it into Camera RAW on the Cintiq it looks terrible, woefully unsaturated. I looked at all the preference settings in Bridge & Camera Raw and I couldn't find one that described the default viewing profile. Changing the export profile (part of the save as dialogue) doesn't change how the files displays in Camera Raw. Therefore, I looked at a number of the Windows Control panel display change screens and they are a mass of conflicting and unintelligible choices. Can someone help me with this. There are about 20 boxes that I need to make choices in the control panel. XP was a great deal simpler and I had no problems with it.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 is definitely capable of using different color profiles for different monitors.

Manually setting a color profile (if your calibration software won't do it for you) for a monitor is done through the color management screen in control panel.

[image: Windows 7 color management screen]

You need to click on 'Add', then on 'Browse' in the screen that appears and find the created profile for the current Device (monitor).

You may need to set the profile as the default after you add it.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the preview in Bridge, you are looking at the embedded JPEG, not the RAW image. (It's the same image you see on the camera's LCD.) The JPEG has all of the noise reduction, sharpening, and vibrance adjustments that the camera adds. The actual RAW image has none of these adjustments applied. If you were using Lightroom rather than ACR in Photoshop, you could have it apply development presets by default that would make the RAW image look more like the JPEG, but that means that the image itself, and not the monitor colour settings, are adjusted. You can save and apply presets as a starting point in Camera RAW, but as far as I know you can't apply them by default on image open.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved your problem, so I thought I would share what helped me.

ICC Profile Version 4 is the default version for the X-Rite profiles.  Unfortunately, it is not supported by all applications.  This drove me crazy for a while because images that looked great in PS and Lightroom looked terrible in most other applications.  Once I started calibrating with ICC Version 2, the problem disappeared.

Until all apps support it, set the ICC Profile Version to 2.

I hope this helps!